# Check in mysql if entry exists and not insert with php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have got a problem with testing out if a string exists in my database!

This is what I've got so far:

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "database", "secret", "user");
if(!$db)
{
exit("Error: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}
$search = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE ip = $client_ip';
$result = mysqli_query($db, $search);



while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
        if (isset($row->blocked)) {
            echo 'You are blocked!';
        } else {
            echo 'You are not blocked!';
        }
```

But this won't work for me.
$client_ip is defined correctly before.

Comment: The client IP address is notoriously unreliable. Be aware that you're likely to catch people you don't intend to and fail to catch some that you do.

Comment: you also need to check the `mysqli_num_rows($result)` to see number of return result before going ahead

Comment: @Saqueib before checking rows, we should check whether `$result` is false, as a failed query will return false by `mysqli_query()`

Comment: where  $client_ip came from?

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap `$client_ip` in quotes as it is a string:

```
$search = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ip = '$client_ip'";
```

Comment: You need to call `mysqli_error()` to see what error mysql is reporting as that is correct syntax.

Comment: You can echo `$search` to find out the resultant SQL .

Comment: not a php dev, but i belive it needs to be:
$search = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ip = '" + $client_ip + "'";

Comment: @JordanFryar + is invalid character of concatination in php, use dot(.)

Comment: @JordanFryar $search = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ip = '" . $client_ip . "'";  -- in php dot(.) is used for concatenation not plus(+)

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
$search = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ip = '{$client_ip}'";
```

Comment: Please add some explanation as well to make it more clear what is the fix.